# How to mount an EFS volume on AWS Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have tried to follow the normal (non-studio) documentation on mounting an EFS file system, as can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/mount-an-efs-file-system-to-an-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-with-lifecycle-configurations/), however, these steps don't work in a studio notebook. Specifically, the `sudo mount -t nfs ...` does not work in both the Image terminal and the system terminal.

How do I mount an EFS file system that already exists to amazon Sagemaker, so I can access the data/ datasets I stored in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I spoke to an AWS Solutions Architect, and he confirms that EFS is not supported on Sagemaker Studio.

---

**Workaround:**

Instead of mounting your old EFS, you can mount the SageMaker studio EFS onto an EC2 instance, and copy over the data manually. You would need the correct EFS storage volume id, and you'll find your newly copied data available in Sagemaker Studio. *I have not actually done this though.*

To find the EFS id, look at the section "Manage your storage volume" [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-tasks.html#manage-your-storage-volume).

Comment: Amazon SageMaker Studio supports EFS, but its created when you create the SageMaker Studio Domain, so its not a custom EFS that you've already created, its created as part of onboarding SageMaker Studio - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/onboard-iam.html

Comment: @PeterWilson, I would say that means it doesn't **support** EFS. It uses 1 EFS volume to support itself. Instead, in Studio, you have to copy over the data from your existing EFS volume. This is what my answer states.

Comment: Is something changed since then? Since I am still not able to do that. In addition, mounting the SageMaker studio EFS onto an EC2 is not a good solution, as the studio directory is in some sense hidden (not really, but they are located in internal folders).

Answer (score 0):

As per the previous Re:Invent, the new SageMaker Studio experience now supports the mounts of a custom EFS. You can refer to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/domain-custom-efs.html) for this.